# Debugging Firebase Crash Report - CALayer position contains NAN

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

By looking at the generated crash reports, I could see that this error appears a lot. However, it's really hard to tell what is causing it to fail:

```
Exception name: CALayer position contains NaN:
```

In my code, I have a NSTimer that removes a custom `MKAnnotation` that contains animated `CALayers` after X delay. I'm guessing that I need to call `view.layer removeAllAnimations` before calling `removeFromSuperView`.

Currently, I'm only calling `removeFromSuperView`.

**Stack log:**

```
Exception name: CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 163.74]
__exceptionPreprocess + 1241536
objc_exception_throw + 34136
+[NSException raise:format:] + 1241348
CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) + 1101236
-[CALayer setPosition:] + 1101608
-[CALayer setFrame:] + 1103040
-[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 39996
Mapbox (4306594984 + 60584)
Mapbox (4306593356 + 58956)
Mapbox (4306685072 + 150672)
Mapbox (4306682568 + 148168)
__NSFireDelayedPerform + 998556
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether you are using the animations in the view which with you might have applied constraints. In such case, it can be created a snapshot of a view and apply animations on that view. After completion remove the snapshot view.

```
[viewObject snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Comment: Hmm.. How are you sure that this is causing the issue?

Comment: Hello Friend, I just want to share the animations technique application for constraints. The issue might not be due to this reason. :)